# control the sorting in for loop BASH

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to control the sorting that occurs when I run a, for d in * ; do; echo $i; done; in my directory?  I have this folder structure:

```
root/
  |__CloudUtils/
  |__ComponentSplit/
  |__ComponentStatistics/
  |__ETLManager/
  |__MergeComponent/
  |__NormalizeComponent/
  |__Reducer/
```

And I want to change the order so mvn will compile NormalizeComponent second right after CloudUtils.

```
for d in */ ; do
    d=${d::-1}
    mvn clean deploy -f "$d"
done
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is the logic of the sort order that you want? If you just want to process a specific file first, don't do it in the loop.

Comment: If your goal in `${d::-1}` is to strip the `/` off the end, using `${d%/}` is more explicit to readers about that intent (and has the added benefit that it won't strip anything that _isn't_ a `/`)

Comment: Given this directory structure, wouldn't this then be `for d in root/*` or `cd root; for d in *` instead of the code you posted? In both cases, the filename generation should already be done alphabetically sorted under bash.

Comment: For more complex dependencies, wouldn't be using a _Makefile_ a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on Charles's answer:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
exception='NormalizeComponent'
dirs=( !("$exception")/ )
dirs=( "${dirs[0]}" "$exception"/ "${dirs[@]:1}" )
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  echo "$d"
done
```

outputs

```
CloudUtils/
NormalizeComponent/
ComponentSplit/
ComponentStatistics/
ETLManager/
MergeComponent/
Reducer/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the sort results only insofar as there exists a collation order that matches what you need; `LC_COLLATE` can be used to pick the ordering to use -- but in this case, none of the ones your operating system ships will match the behavior you want.

---

You can use an [extglob with a negative assertion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) to leave specific directories out of the glob's result, so you can hardcode the first and second items, and do everything else in the ordering the locale's collation settings provide:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "ERROR: only bash is supported" >&2; exit 1; }

shopt -s extglob
for d in CloudUtils NormalizeComponent !(CloudUtils|NormalizeComponent)/; do
    mvn clean deploy -f "${d%/}"
done
```